# Loading Bokeh in Jupyter Notebook returns: TypeError: a.Operator is undefined

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, bokeh, conda

## My system specs

### Python

```
'3.4.5 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  5 2016, 14:53:07) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]'
```

### Jupyter Notebook

```
# packages in environment at C:\Anaconda3:
#
notebook                  4.3.0                    py35_0  
notebook                  5.0.0.dev                 <pip>
```

### Bokeh

```
Name: bokeh
Version: 0.12.5.dev11
Summary: Interactive plots and applications in the browser from Python
Home-page: http://github.com/bokeh/bokeh
Author: Continuum Analytics
Author-email: info@continuum.io
License: New BSD
Location: c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh-0.12.5.dev11-py3.5.egg
Requires: six, requests, PyYAML, python-dateutil, Jinja2, numpy, tornado
```

## Problem

When I try to run the following in a Jupyter Notebook cell:

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from bokeh.resources import INLINE
output_notebook(resources=INLINE)
```

It returns this:

```
Loading BokehJS ...
Javascript error adding output!
TypeError: a.Operator is undefined
See your browser Javascript console for more details.
```

What gives? Things used to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I note you are running a "dev build" version. The publication of dev builds is primarily a means for the project itself to develop and test its own automated release infrastructure, and secondarily is a way for interested users to more easily obtain "bleeding edge" versions without having to build from source. However, they are not subject to anywhere near the testing and scrutiny that a real full release receives. They are provided as-is, in case they happen to be useful, without any other guarantees.

There were some fairly invasive recent changes to remove some dependencies from BokehJS and make it smaller. I have been using Bokeh in notebooks without issue, but perhaps there is some version-specific issue to resolve. I would recommend filing a bug report on the GitHub issue tracker with all this information:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues

Comment: thank you for the quick reply! [I just opened an issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5814)

Comment: In case anybody else runs into this problem here is the link for the [workaround solution](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5814#issuecomment-275869654). Thanks again @bigreddot!

Comment: Thanks for helping us find this build issue, it will be resolved for future releases.